# How to disable physical windows button and touch screen (not a touchpad) edge swipe gesture on Windows 10 tablets?

Tags: windows-10

For some reason we have a business application running on Windows 10 tablets that will want to keep the user in the app, but not going to the desktop or have any access to other windows features/UI.

That comes to 2 issues:

1. how to disable the windows physical button? For Microsoft surface it can be achievable by disabling the "Windows Start button" driver in device manager, but for other tablet brands like dell, acer....there is no such a device in device manger, is there any other way to do so?
2. how to disable the swipe from the edge gesture? Can it be done through registry?

Any insightful thoughts on these is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old post, but just solved my own issue. After the Windows 10 Anniversary Update there is now a GPO setting called "Enable Edge Swipe" that you can disable.

1. Open Group Policy Editor.
2. Navigate to ComputerConfig > AdminTemp > WindowsComp > EdgeUI > AllowEdgeSwipe

Comment: You can request an account merge to make it easier to keep track of your questions and answers (and reputation!): http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts